# jqGrid bindKeys

Tags: jqgrid

I use jqGrid and want the grid to be scrollable by keys. The UP/DOWN functionality should be just like [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithInlineEditingOnEnter.htm), but when a user pressed ENTER or clicks on a row, a user is redirected to a different page.

What I have so far is

- Code that redirects a user to a different page in onSelectRow
- .jqGrid('bindKeys')

Two problems now:

- When pressing UP/DOWN a user goes to a different row and then the code in onSelectRow is executed. How do I prevent that?
- When pressing UP/DOWN, the entire screen scrolls a little bit. How do I prevent screen scrolling from happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to address the first issue of onSelectRow being fired on UP/DOWN by checking the event parameter that this method receives for keyCode 38 and 40. That allowed me to scroll the grid without executing my code in onSelectRow. The second issue of the entire screen moving somehow went away "on its own".